# `ng serve` fails if service is not provided directly in component

Tags: angular, angular2-injection

I have a project structured like so:

```
project
-src
--app
---project
----project.component.ts
----project.component.html
----project.component.sass
---project.module.ts
---project.service.ts
```

From within my component I am attempting to use the service:

```
constructor(private ProjectService: ProjectService) {
    this.ProjectService = ProjectService;
}
```

But when I run `ng serve` it fails saying `ERROR in /Users/jrquick/uabshp/project/src/app/project/project.component.ts (9,49): Cannot find name 'ProjectService'`

Even though I have the service in the project.module.ts file:

```
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ProjectComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    providers: [
        ProjectService
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        ProjectComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        ProjectComponent,
        ProjectService
    ]
})
```

I have tried adding it to my component annotation's providers array but I'd prefer the service is used a singleton. I can also directly import the service in the project.compontent.ts file (like below) but it is not ideal to have to have the same import statement copy and pasted within the module as well as multiples components and services.

```
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';
```

project.service.ts declaration:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DefaultVariableService {
    constructor() {

    }

   ...
}
```

Comment: have you used the `@Injectable()` annotation on service ?

Comment: I have, I added the declaration for the service to the question too.

Comment: you need to specify the import on every component you plan to use this service

Comment: Thanks @RahulSingh, I was hoping otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, because you trying import *ProjectService* from the same folder in which *ProjectComponent* is located. Your import of *ProjectService* in **project.component.ts** should look like

```
import { ProjectService } from '../project.service';
```

Secondly, why do you use strange stuff like:

```
constructor(private ProjectService: ProjectService) {
    this.ProjectService = ProjectService;
}
```

What is the purpose of this?! I think that it should look like:

```
constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) {

}
```

and that's all! You can use this service in your component in this way:

```
this.projectService.someMethod()
```

Comment: I have tried that and it works, however, since the service is inject as a provider in the module is not automatically available to all components and services within the same module? Or is it required to be injected in the module as well as all of the components and services that require it?

Comment: @jrquick No it is not you need to tell angular about the import of the service

Comment: @jrquick I believe Jaroslaw is correct. I think this.ProjectService = ProjectService is the issue. You don't need that line

Comment: I am new to Angular 4, migrating from 1 at the moment. The guide I am using shows the constructor setting the services on to `this`. I have tried without but then get errors on the lines where I call the service, I will look further into it though. Thanks @JaroslawK.

Comment: @jrquick looking through the angular tutorials, it does look like they do that for their examples. that statement is needed if you do not declare if the service is public or private. constructor(projectService: ProjectService){}. If you do add public/private then the compiler automatically creates a property and does the assignment for you.